# Saving notepad file into a database (Microsoft Access)

Tags: ms-access, vb6, file-import

How do I import a Notepad file into VB 6.0 and then save the content of the file into a database (Microsoft Access database)?

Comment: There is no file such as a `Notepad file'. I think you are referring to text files in general.

Answer (score 1):

Basic steps (for any language/database):

1. Read the file
2. Connect to a database using a connection string
3. Insert into tables

Refer [Connecting Access 2003 with Visual Basic 6](http://visualbasic.ittoolbox.com/documents/connecting-access-2003-with-visual-basic-6-11826) for specific information and code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna read between the lines here and guess you are refering to some kind of tablular data held in a text file.

If this is the case then perhaps the Jet (or ODBC) connection strings found [here](http://connectionstrings.com/textfile) (along with a schema.ini file) may be what you are looking for.

You can then use ADODB recordsets to select data from the text file and insert it into you Access database.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'm doing this a lot lately. So, assuming you've got a reference set to SCRRUN.DLL, this first function will read the file (and will cope with ANSI and Unicode):

```
Function ReadFileE(Filename As Variant) As String
    Dim oStream As scripting.TextStream
    Dim sData As String

    Set oFSO = New scripting.FileSystemObject
    sData = vbNullString
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oStream = oFSO.OpenTextFile(Filename, ForReading, False, TristateMixed)
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        sData = oStream.ReadAll
        oStream.Close
    Else
        sData = vbNullString
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
        ReadFileE = sData
End Function
```

The following functions I use to open a database and query it:

```
Function OpenMDB(sFile As Variant) As Variant  ' ADODB.Connection
    Dim nErr As Long
    Dim sErr As String
    Dim oConnection As Object 'ADODB.Connection
    Set oConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    On Error Resume Next
    oConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & sFile
    nErr = Err.Number
    sErr = Err.Description
    On Error GoTo 0
    If nErr <> 0 Then
    Err.Raise OPENDATABASE_E_NOTFOUND, , sErr
    End If
    Set OpenMDB = oConnection
End Function

Function QueryMDB(ByRef oDB As Variant, sQuery As Variant, Optional bCmdText As Boolean = False) As Variant ''ADODB.Connection ADODB.Recordset
    Const adOpenForwardOnly  As Long = 0
    Const adOpenStatic As Long = 3
    Const adOpenDynamic As Long = 2
    Const adOpenKeyset As Long = 1
    Const adLockOptimistic As Long = 3
    Const adCmdText As Long = 1
    Dim oRecordSet As Object 'ADODB.Recordset
    Set oRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")
    oRecordSet.Open sQuery, oDB, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic
    Set QueryMDB = oRecordSet
End Function
```

And now a bit of sample code:

```
Dim sText As String
sText = ReadFileE("c:\windows\system32\SQLSRDME.TXT")
Dim db As Variant
Dim rs as Variant
set db = OpenMDB("c:\users\bruce\documents\database.mdb")
set rs = QueryMDB( db, "SELECT * FROM Table1" )
rs.Find "Field1='SQLSRDME.TXT'"
If Not rs.EOF Then
    rs("Field2") = sText
    rs.Update
End If
rs.Close
db.Close
```

That last bit was typed off the top of my head, so it may have holes. The other code is out a Class file that is used daily.

Also, the class file code is exposed in a COM object, thus the preponderance of `Variant` declarations.

HTH.

Answer (score -2):

You might try to load the notepad file using Microsoft Excel and then try to get it into Microsoft Acces from there.

Comment: Why to make the process complex by importing a simple text document to Microsoft Excel and then using a module to read the spreadsheet; when you can simply read the text file?

Comment: Access and Excel copy/paste works pretty well between the two, so that's why I suggested this as worth a try

Comment: The poster wants to do it programmatically using Visual Basic 6. However, your method requires manual intervention.